# Why there is the difference between Response.Redirect vs new RedirectResult()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

When I redirect like this way

```
 protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("https://mydom.com");
 }
```

so the browser redirects to **http://mydom.com/httpS://mydom.com**

but if I redirect this way

```
 protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
      var res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
      filterContext.Result = res.Redirect("https://mydom.com");
 }
```

so the browser redirect correctly to **https://mydom.com**

**Why** there is the difference?

Comment: well, you've already stated the difference :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `RedirectResult` is a class whereas `HttpResponse.Redirect` is a method. While the former redirects the user to a specified URI the latter will redirect you to a given URL. To see the differences between URL and URI [see here](http://www.damnhandy.com/2007/11/19/uri-vs-url-whats-the-difference/).

Hope that helps

Comment: In reflector I saw what RedirectResult does `string url = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(this.Url, context.HttpContext);
    context.Controller.TempData.Keep();
    context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url, false);
`, so as I can see ReidrectResult also redirects to URL and not URI. What I miss?

Comment: @theateist Apparently, HttpResponse.Redirect uses true as a default value and therefore terminates the action immediately. Whereas RedirectResult, if your code is what it uses, does not terminate the action immediately.