# Redirect to another website from post action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `post` action that upon success i want to redirect the user to another website.
this is my action code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegistartionComplete(Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db1.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db1.SaveChanges();
            return Redirect(@"http://www.google.com");
        }
        return View(customer);
    }
```

the problem is that after the `db1.SaveChanges()` is executed I'm getting redirected to the same page (according to the url) but with an `Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage` message.  when testing with a break point i see that the `return Redirect(@"http://www.google.com");` is executed but it just returns me to the same action view.

Comment: Are you really redirecting to google.com or is that just for illustration here?  Have you confirmed with Fiddler (or with the Network tab of the browser developer tools, etc) that the redirect really isn't happening?  I believe that some browsers will not update the URL when a redirect leads to a page that fails to load.  So if your destination is failing to load (which you could see in Fiddler, etc), you'd get the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Are you sure that db1.SaveChanges() is not throwing an exception?

Comment: @Erv currently for testing purposes i'm redirecting to google. this is the exact code that i'm using.
@Mariusz the `SaveChanges()` command isn't throwing any errors (tried it also with `try\catch`).

Comment: please check the following issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024864/why-there-is-the-difference-between-response-redirect-vs-new-redirectresult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though everything should be running as expected, and worked fine in my test.  I would suggest trying the following:

- Try the redirect without changing the entity state and saving.  Just do the redirect if the model is valid.
- Possibly try wrapping the return View(customer) in an ELSE block.  I know it shouldn't be hitting that if the model is valid, but I have seen crazier things happen.